# Specialize template member inside template definition

Tags: c++, templates

It is possible to specialize some class member function outside the template definition:

```
template<class A>
struct B {
   void f();   
};

template<>
void B<int>::f() { ... }

template<>
void B<bool>::f() { ... }
```

and in this case I can even omit definition of function `f` for a general type `A`.

But how to put this specializations inside the class? Like this:

```
template<class A>
struct B {
   void f();   

   void f<int>() { ... }
   void f<bool>() { ... }
};
```

What syntax should I use in this case?

EDIT: 
For now the solution with fewest lines of code is to add a fake template function `f` definition and explicitly call it from original function `f`:

```
template<class A>
struct B {
   void f() { f<A>(); }

   template<class B> 
   void f();

   template<> 
   void f<int>() { ... }

   template<> 
   void f<bool>() { ... }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `B::f` a template function within your struct:

```
struct B {
    template <typename T>
    void f();

    template<>
    void f<int>() { ... }

    template<>
    void f<bool>() { ... }
};
```

Edit:

According to your comment this may help you, but I've not tested if it works:

```
template <typename A>
struct B {
    template <typename T = A>
    void f() { ... }

    template<>
    void f<int>() { ... }

    template<>
    void f<bool>() { ... }
};
```

Comment: Its possible but in my case this function are depend from the same type. As an explanation... f() returning some enum. Like this: `virtual TType f<int>( return tt_int; }`. And called in such a manner: `TType type = obj.f();`

Comment: You are very close... All you need is to add `void f() { f<A>(); }`

Comment: @ZAB - You mean at the general template declaration? This gives me another idea. What about setting `A` as default template argument. I will edit the code above to reflect that.

Comment: Function templates have no default template arguments in C++03.

Answer (score 6):

You should put the specialization on the `struct`:

```
template<>
struct B<int> {
   void f() { ... }
};

template<>
struct B<bool> {
   void f() { ... }
};
```

There is no way to specialize member functions in the same class the templated version is defined in. Either you must explicitly specialize the member function outside of the class, or specialize an entire class with the member function in it.

Comment: I don't want to specialize the struct, just one member function. It's an "Explicit Specialization of Members of Class Templates".

Comment: @ZAB: Then use the syntax you described in the first part of your question. See my edited answer for clarification.

Comment: But why? It makes no sense. For what reason compiler prohibit my willness to put definution of function iside the scope of a template?

Comment: @ZAB: because one definition of a class shall always consist of the definition one type. Each different instantiated version of a class (specialized or not) is a different type. Allowing you to specialize different version of `f`'s in one class/struct definition would allow you to describe different types in one definition.

Comment: Yep! And as I say I dont need to define new class. So why I can specialize this function outside the class and can't specialize it inside? From aside, from linker point of view there is no problem. Its all about the syntax. To put it inside {} or put it outside the {}. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class A>
class B
{
public:
  void f() {
    cout << "any" << endl;
  }
};

template<>
class B<int>
{
public:
  void f() {
    cout << "int" << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{

  B<double> b1;
  b1.f();
  B<int> b2;
  b2.f();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
any
int
```

Anything else is not possible.

Comment: I don't want to specialize the whole struct. Just the member function.